Is this a proper way of grounding a device?
I’m wondering if I can use an unused ground terminal from another device. Is this way correct as in the drawing of my lighting setup?


Is your question "will this work", "is this safe", or "is this allowed"?

The first thing would be to check that the terminal is actually connected to safety ground. Is the ground connection at the top connected to where you intend to insert it or are those separated?

@Hearth The question in the title asks whether this is a proper method, implying whether it is safe or allowed.”
